# ¿Como se puede borrar el valor de una variable?

Tags: python

No sé que comando poner para resetear una variable al terminar una acció. Porfavor, ¿alguien me puede decir como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @Sergi, bienvenido a stackOverflow, si entiendo lo que quieres utiliza el bucle `while`. Para mejor entendimiento de tu pregunta coloca algo de código donde hayas intentado haacer lo que preguntas. Te sugiero leer este apartdao para mejorar tu pregunta y evitar ser cerrada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Depende de que tipo de dato sea tu variable, podrias hacer esto

```
//Con las variables de Tipo String://
PalabraString=" ";
///Para las variables de Tipo Int://
Numero=0;
```

y de igual manera con los otros tipos de variables, como tal, el "resetear" una variable es devolverla al mismo valor que tenia en un inicio, antes de ser utilizada. Con esta logica lo unico que tienes que hacer, es asignarle el valor por defecto como los ejemplos que te di anteriormente.

Un ejemplo claro seria de esta manera:

```
//Estas_variables_son_globales
int a =0;
int b=0;
total=0;

//Este_seria_tu_main_o_metodo
a=...("deme el valor de a"); //entrada de dato "a" ya no vale 0, ahora vale 5
b=...("deme el valor de b"); //entrada de dato "b" ya no vale 0, ahora vale 10
total=a+b;
Mensaje_al_Usuario...("Suma : "+total); //Se le mostraria al usuario 15 que es lo que vale total.
//Se vuelven a poner en cero las variables de clase para que se pueda volver a sumar.
total=0;
a=0;
b=0;
//Repetir con while o Do-while y volveran a estar en 0
```

Espero te ayuda ayudado.